# EF Code First - Fluent API (WithRequiredDependent and WithRequiredPrincipal)

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-relationship, fluent-interface

**I have the following class:**

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Couple Couple { get; set; }
}

public class Couple
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User Groom { get; set; }
    public User Bride { get; set; }
}
```

**Important points:**

1. `Bride` and `Groom` properties are required
2. One-to-one relationship
3. In the `User` class, it is `Couple` required

**DbContext in OnModelCreating**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Couple).WithRequiredPrincipal();
modelBuilder.Entity<Couple>().HasRequired(u => u.Bride).WithRequiredDependent();
modelBuilder.Entity<Couple>().HasRequired(u => u.Groom).WithRequiredDependent();
```

But I can not be required!

All fileds are with null in the database!.

How do I get the fields in the database as not null?
**If possible using the API Flient**.

Answer (score 5):

It should be this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Couple).WithRequiredDependent();
modelBuilder.Entity<Couple>().HasRequired(u => u.Bride).WithRequiredDependent();
modelBuilder.Entity<Couple>().HasRequired(u => u.Groom).WithRequiredDependent();
```

> **How WithRequiredDependent Works** : Configures the relationship to be required:required without a navigation property on the other side of the relationship.  The entity type being configured will be the dependent and contain a foreign key to the principal. The entity
>   type that the relationship targets will be the principal in the relationship.

---

> **Meaning** : Let's consider your first line of code here. It creates a foreign key in the entity being configured (**User**) making it **Dependant** and making the other side of the relationship (**Couple**)  **Principal**

---

**Important :**  Don't you think the configuration you desire will generate a deadlock? I've not tested the code above, but this configuration seems to be a deadlock to me so i'm not sure if EF would allow you to create it. User must need a Couple, and Couple must need that same user i guess.